# Export to ms excel using php and MAMP not Working. Any suggestions?

Tags: php, excel

```
if(isset($_POST['csv'])) {
        require('conexaobd.php'); 
        header("Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=data.csv");   
        $output = fopen("php://output","w");
        fputcsv($output, array("#","Email","Technology","Description","Country","Location","IY","IM","EY","EM","Comments"));
        $query="SELECT * FROM forma1";
        $result=mysqli_query($conn,$query);  
          while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
          fputcsv($output,$row);
          }
          fclose($output);              
}
```

Any suggestions on how to generate the file itself and not only display the content on the screen using MAMP?

Comment: You are outputting HTML, not XLS data. Generating a CSV would be easiest, Excel can open that.

Comment: tks Chris. Now I've tried this code. The content is ok but the file is not being generated. I am using MAMAP, any suggestion?

Comment: Where does it fail? Query runs, `post` is set, etc.

Comment: Actually everything seems to be ok but the download does not happen.  Submit, $_POST, isset  are ok but  only the csv infos are displayed on the canvas/screen like a plain text. My target is to have this file to be downloaded. I'm not sure if it's related to MAMP server.

Comment: You have error reporting on? How do you know everything is okay if it doesn't output anything?

Comment: Yes, mysqli_connect_error() to access the DB. Have echoed "connected successfully" to make sure the infos are being reached. Do have any suggestion what kind of error reporting I am run to fetch this kind of inconsistence? Tks